# How to change icon files with code constant on xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, application-settings

I'm building an app that has a Free version and Paid version.
The difference between the apps are only a define line of some constant in the code (it creates the code needed to add on each app).

I want the icons to change too according to this definition. Does someone knows how can I do that? can I choose for example between different info.plist files using code generated?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to setup a duplicate Target of your main target for your lite version. In this secondary target, it should be identical except for a `PREPROCESSOR MACRO` that you add like `LITE_VERSION`. It should also point to a different info.plist

Then, in the code at compile time, you can use `#ifdef LITE_VERSION` to compile Lite code vs Reg Code when you compile for that target.

Comment: I know I can use PREPROCESSOR MACRO, But how I choose between two plist files? where?

Comment: In your second target (Lite), look for the "Info.plist file" under Build Settings: http://cloud.coneybeare.net/HvO1  You can change it to anything you would like and you should change it to a duplicate Info.plist file that you create.

Comment: No programmable way to change those settings? only from the GUI?

Comment: Yes, by making a second target, you will never have to manually change them after the first time. You just select the different target to build for in the drop down menu in the title bar when you want to build lite, or pro.

Comment: OMG! you just saved me tons of extra time figuring everything out, Thank you!
I still haven't figure out how to duplicate the target elegantly (with new name that I want) but still it's an amazing improvment.